# Store values of different arrays with same key in PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter

I stuck with my code and I am new to Php. How to store values of different arrays with same key in PHP ?.

> for array 1: [0]=>31,[1]=>42, [2]=>21, .....
>
> for array 2: [0]=>21,[1]=>21,[2]=>24, .....
>
> for array 3: [0]=>45,[1]=>34,[2]=>45, ....

I tried to get a Output as :

> [0]=>S5001:31,21,45|[1]=>S5002:42,21,34|[2]=>S5003:21,24,45.......[N]S50..N-1:21,23,45.

where S5001,S5002, are the keys of array1,array2,array3 ....

```
$student_marks_entered1=$this->input->post('mark1');
$student_marks_entered2=$this->input->post('mark2');
$student_marks_entered3=$this->input->post('mark3');
foreach($student_marks_entered1 as $key=>$value1)
{
$marks_arr1[]=$value1;                  
}
foreach($student_marks_entered2 as $key=>$value2)
{
$marks_arr2[]=$value2;
}
foreach($student_marks_entered3 as $key=>$value3)
{
$marks_arr3[]=$value3;
}
```

**Desired Output is:**

```
S5001:31,21,45|S5002:42,21,34|S5003:21,24,45.......S50..N-1:21,23,45
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use below code

```
<?php
$names = array( 0=>"S5001",1=>"S5002",2=>"S5003" );
$student_marks_entered1=array(31,42,21);
$student_marks_entered2=array(21,21,24);
$student_marks_entered3=array(45,34,45);

foreach($names as $key=>$name)
{
    $newArr[$key] = $name.":".$student_marks_entered1[$key].",".$student_marks_entered2[$key].",".$student_marks_entered3[$key];
}

$finalStr = implode("|", $newArr);
echo $finalStr;
```

**Output:**

```
S5001:31,32,33|S5002:42,44,46|S5003:21,23,25
```

**Demo :  [Click Here](https://eval.in/685202)**

Comment: index is missing in array... please correct it as $tmpstr[$key].....  in foreach($names as $key=>$name)
{
    $tmpstr [$key]= $name.":".$student_marks_entered1[$key].".....
}

Comment: yeh now it is marked as correct answer.. it is done by mistake.. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using for loop get all value by there key..
See below code.

```
$student_marks_entered1=array(31,42,21);
$student_marks_entered2=array(21,21,24);
$student_marks_entered3=array(45,34,45);
$name=5000;
for($i=0; $i<3;$i++){
    $var=$name + $i + 1;
    $pipe=$i < 2 ? '|' : '';
    echo "S".$var.":". $student_marks_entered1[$i].','.$student_marks_entered2[$i].",".$student_marks_entered3[$i].$pipe;
}
```

[demo and example](http://phpio.net/s/1abn)

Comment: Its wrong.Extra Pipe `|` sign coming at last in output.

Comment: @RJParikh check now.

Comment: its like $pipe=$i < 2 ? '|' : '';